# How to resize created array by one function in the another function?

Tags: arrays, c, realloc

I created an array in one function (say func1) with `calloc` with the size of 0. Now I need another function (say func2) to resize (i.e. `realloc`) that array and populate its elements there.
Then in func1 I shall access the elements of the resized array.

I couldn't figure out how I could do so.

Edit: I've been requested to show my faulty code by some respondents. Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int func2(int *arr, int option, int * asize)
{
    int err = 0;
    switch(option)
    {
        case 1:
            arr = (int *)realloc(arr, 2 * sizeof(int));
            if(arr == NULL)
            {
                err = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                // got to manually populate
                *(arr++) = 3;
                *(arr) = 5;
                *asize = 2;
                err = 0;
            }
            break;
        default:
            arr = (int *)realloc(arr, 1 * sizeof(int));
            if(arr == NULL)
            {
                err = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                *(arr) = 1;
                *asize = 1;
                err = 0;
            }
            break;
    }
    return err;
}

void func1(void)
{
    int *iptr, asize = 0;

    // created an array to size and populate later
    iptr = (int *)calloc(0, sizeof(int));
    if(iptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("no array created!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("array created! attempt to resize...\n");
        int option = 1;
        if(!func2(iptr, option, &asize))
        {
            printf("resized successfully\n");
            iptr = iptr - asize - 1; // rewinding to the fist element
            for(int i=0; i<asize; i++)
            {
                printf("i=%d, cont=%d\n", i, *(iptr+1));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("resizing failed!");
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    func1();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show the code you have as a [mre] and describe what you want to achieve by resizing in a different funciton please. Why first create with zero size and then increase?

Comment: @Yunnosch, thanks for your response. As requested, I have placed my simplified code from my problem.

Answer (score 1):

`realloc` gives your memory allocator the opportunity to just extend or reduce the amount of space a pointer is allowed to access without having to copy anything, and then handles the copying if it does need to allocate more space.

it will then return either the pointer you gave it ( if the change was in-place ), or a pointer to the new place the data is ( the old pointer is freed, so don't use it again ). if you get a NULL it means you gave it size 0 and it just free'd your data, or for an actual size change the allocation failed and your original pointer is still valid but size is unchanged.

the problem you have is that func1 will still have the original pointer.

the easiest solutions are letting func2 return the new pointer, or update it in a global value they share if that's fine for your program, or func1 can pass func2 a pointer to the pointer, and func2 can use and update the data via that indirection.

you could put the pointer to the pointer in a struct and have some helper functions around it if you wanted a more structured approach to sharing it ( kind of like how golang passes structs of { void * pointer, int size, int cap } ( cap is unused but allocated part of an array, so golang can realloc without calling realloc immediately )

you can then do locks or whatever if you'll be threading around the array and keep them in that structure and let the helpers assist with keeping things cool.

if you don't have to worry about any of that, just returning the pointer from the function in either a return value or as a **out parameter should do.

---

what are pointers and arrays?

C is different that most high level languages. In most languages, an array is a datastructure that you manipulate. It grows and shrinks and might have a bunch of metadata associated with it and functions for manipulating it. This isn't C.

Imagine you have an `int`. Let's say it takes 4 bytes of memory somewhere. In C, you can ask the `malloc` function to find you 4 bytes of memory you can use to store your `int`. `malloc(4)`. How does `malloc` tell you where to put your `int`? Imagine you numbered the bytes of your computers memory from 0-<however-many-bytes-you-have>. Malloc returns the offset where your memory is stored. It will never move around or change size or whatever. It's just four bytes at some specific offset into memory. if it's 100 bytes in, your pointer will be 100. If it's 1,000,000,000 bytes in, that will be your pointer value. The important thing to remember is that pointers are *values*. They are a number representing how far into memory your data is. If you pass a pointer, you're passing that offset into memory. That number. Just like you would an integer.

So you can't just change the value passed in, because you just got a copy of the number, not a reference to the original number you can update.

So what is an array in C? Well, if you request space for 10 `int`s, `malloc(sizeof(int) * 10)`, you've now requested a chunk of memory 40 bytes across. Say it's at offset 1000 into your computers memory. You just have 40 bytes. So you can imagine the first 4 bytes are the first `int`, the second four bytes are the second `int`, etc.

When you pass your array to `func1` from `func2`, it does what's called "decaying" into a pointer. The only thing that is passed when you put the name of an array as a parameter is the pointer to it's first element, that offset into memory where your values are sitting.

So `func1` just knows your `int`s are sitting 1000 into your computer memory, because it got 1000 for the pointer value.

When you realloc, it might say "hey your data is still at 1000", or it might say "hey, there wasn't room to make that array from 10 `int`s into 100, so I copied the data to a new offset that is 7000 into memory.

it's just telling you a new position where your data has been copied to. this information, this number 7000 must now be communicated back to your original function.

you could return the pointer and overwrite the pointer in the original function. or you could do something that's very normal in C, but seems complex coming from languages with objects and referencing semantics etc.

Instead of passing the value of the pointer ( 100 ) in your original call, you could pass a pointer to where your pointer in that first function is.

```c
// returning the value example

void hello(){
  int * data = malloc( sizeof(int) * 10 );
  ... check errors, zero memory and use 10 ints in array
  data = world( data );
  ... use 100 ints now in array
}

int * world( int * data ){
  int * data = realloc( data, sizeof(int) * 100 );
  ... check errors, zero new ints, and use now larger array
  return data
}
```

how would hello know how large the new array is? you'd have to pass a size around somewhere, since C expects *you* to keep track of silly stuff like "how large are my arrays". It certainly won't stop you from writing to the 100th element of a 5 element array, and accidentally overwriting whatever happens to be there in memory ( the classic buffer overflow is caused by writing on past the end of a C array ).

```c
// what if we pass a pointer instead?

void hello(){
  int entries = 10 ;
  int * data = malloc( sizeof(int) * entries );
  ... error checking, zeroing memory, doing things with entries=10
  world( &data, &entries );
  ... doing things with entries=100, and knowing because the other
  ... function updated the value of entries via the pointer we gave
  ... to it!
}

void world( int ** data, int * entries ){
  int newentries = 100 ;
  int * newdata = realloc( *data, sizeof(int) * newentries );
  ... check for NULL ( allocation failure ), zero new memory
  // we overwrite the variables in the caller through the pointers
  *data = newdata ;
  *entries = newentries ;
}
```

more complex, but also more functionality. as you can see, things start getting a little more complex as you add pointers, but also more powerful.

they are super fiddly, super hairy, and you can easily overwrite and mess up memory all over your program by making a mistake, which is why so many shy away from C.

but they are fast!

you can use pointers to pointers to pointers if it makes sense for manipulating data, but be aware that being a [***three star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) is a pejorative for a reason :)

Comment: thank you a lot for your explanations. May you please look at my codes I placed newly? I know I am trying to "catch my left ear with the right hand" but nevertheless, I'd be greatfull if you can look at it and suggest me the right path. Thanks

Comment: @Bakyt I hope some of that helps. I didn't use your code precisely, but tried to explain what is going on with some examples

Comment: Thank you a lot. Your explanation and examples were brilliant and fully resolved my issue. Have a wonderful day/evening!